# Safe SRSW and safe MRSW registers

Tags: java, concurrency

Both "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" by Herlihy, Shavit and "Concurrent and Distributed Computing in Java" by Vijay K. Garg books refer to Java fields as examples of safe SRSW-registers. The latter even provides a sample data structure for it:

```
public class SafeSRSWBoolean implements Register<Boolean> {

    private boolean value;

    @Override
    public Boolean read() {

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Boolean value) {
                this.value = value;
    }
}
```

My question is why can't it be a MRSW register as well? It seems it satisfies the conditions for it cause the reader is not a writer, it doesn't modify the data structure.

Comment: Some discussion [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44527/difference-between-srsw-and-mrsw-safe-boolean-registers).

Comment: I saw that either. But don't understand fully. I wish someone will help with a more comprehensive answer.